# How to get folder from assets?

Tags: android, android-file, android-assets

```
File directory = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"folder");
```

The above code can get a folder in the memory card as a File. Then I use the `File` class to get the files in the folder.

How can I get a folder from the assets as a `File` object?

Comment: Go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)

Answer (score 0):

There is no "absolute path for a file existing in the asset folder". You can use following code to fetch details from assets folder,

```
uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("//assets/aaa/aaa.txt"));
```

Comment: is there a way of making it as a File object? and instead of pointing to a file i want it pointing to a directory instead?

Comment: for example

new File("assets/folder");

Comment: You can use that url as filepath for File Object.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below :

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open(file:///android_asset/foldername/filename);
File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File(my_file_name);
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

return null;
}
```

Use below code to get the Assets folders and files into an array of Strings.

```
     final AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            // for assets folder add empty string
                        String[] filelist = assetManager.list("");
                        // for assets/subFolderInAssets add only subfolder name
                        String[] filelistInSubfolder = assetManager.list("subFolderInAssets");
            if (filelist == null) {
                // dir does not exist or is not a directory
            } else {
                for (int i=0; i<filelist.length; i++) {
                    // Get filename of file or directory
                    String filename = filelist[i];
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i'll check this one out :D

Comment: What you want to get exactly ? @user2982786

Comment: well....like my code above...the directory is pointing to a folder..not a file...can it be done if the folder i want to point to is in the assets folder?

Comment: The above code is you can use to point to folder also. Just do not add file name into it.

Comment: now i got one last question...why is it slower to get files in the assets folder than getting files in the storage

Comment: @user2982786 Better you go for some R&D.